# filter payload by some values and remove other whole payload

Tags: mule, dataweave

i have the following requirement 
this is the input i need to allow only statusEvent.type:"Proof_approved"
>

```
{
    "statusEvent": {
        "type": "PROOF_APPROVED",
        "status": "WAITING_FOR_INPUT",
        "eventDate": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
        "modifyDate": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
        "userName": "educator@school.edu (educator%40school.edu)",
        "userOrgId": "1321231",
        "quoteLineId":"testid1"
        "packageConfiguration": [
            {
                "packageId": [
                    "AIM_PACKAGE1"
                ],
                "component": [
                    "Handbook"
                ],
                "fieldName": [
                    "Upload Handbook Document"
                ],
                "assetUrl": [
                    "sflydamlocation.handbookfilename1.pdf"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

out put like:

> (below should be only payload with type "type": "PROOF_APPROVED", )

```
{
  "name": payload.statusevent.userName,
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "quoteLineId": payload.statusevent.quoteLineId,
      "package": payload.statusevent.packageconfiguration
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not clear how your input relates to your output. Do you have an example of a valid output from your given input?

Comment: Also you should mention if this is for DataWeave 1 (Mule 3.x) or DataWeave 2 (Mule 4.x).

Answer (score 0):

If that input JSON was an array, you can use `filter` to filterthe records. Something like:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ($.statusEvent.'type'=="PROOF_APPROVED") map{
      "quoteLineId": $.statusEvent.quoteLineId,
      "package": $.statusEvent.packageConfiguration
}
```